# How much front-end design must be done before every Sprint in Scrum?

Tags: design, scrum, user-experience, sprint

I'm a front-end developer working as a member of an agile team. I have no clue how much of UI/UX must be done before every sprint and how much of it I can postpone for later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no universal answer to this. However, we can draw some conclusions.

Some amount of design (both "front end" UI or UX design as well as "back end") must be done in order to refine a Product Backlog Item. Without some design information, it will be hard to add "detail, estimates, and order" to the Product Backlog Item while performing Product Backlog Refinement.

Some level of design, which may be more or not, must be done before Sprint Planning in order to enable a team to adequately determine what work can be done within the Sprint and to create a plan for completing that work.

Aside from that, it's up to the team. It's also a balancing act - more up-front design is time and energy away from producing working software, but it also increases knowledge and reduces risk. Some teams have a working agreement called the Definition of Ready (not defined in the Scrum Guide) that defines exactly what is the minimum bar for a Product Backlog Item to be ready for refinement and/or ready for Sprint Planning.

Comment: tnx forr your asnwer, would it be possible to clarify it with a simple example

Comment: @Majz I'm not sure what type of example you would be looking for.

Comment: imagine we have some stories about creating a web page for ticket reservation for next sprint, what part of UI must be done beforehand.

Comment: @Majz It's up to the team. You need to do enough to ensure that the team can effectively perform Product Backlog Refinement before Product Backlog Refinement and enough before Sprint Planning to ensure the team can effectively perform Sprint Planning. If you don't have good working agreements with the team that define this, it may be good to work with the whole team to make them.